# C# Date Format Change in to MM/DD/YY in C# List

Tags: c#, list, date-format

Well I need to use Date Format `dd/mm/yy` instead of `mm/dd/yy`.
Any solution where i can change the date format into `dd/mm/yy` can anyone guide me please.

```
DataTable others = ds.Tables["items"];
List<Items> ItemList = new List<Items>();
foreach (DataRow dr in others.Rows)
{
    ItemList.Add(new Items { date_for = dr["date_for"].ToString() });
 }
```

Comment: You can use DateTime.Parse(dr["date_for"]).ToString("dd/mm/yy");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628858/convert-date-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3):

Parse the string into a `DateTime` and ouput it back with `ToString`, each time specifying the format:

```
var input = "12/31/99"; // dr["date_for"]
var output = DateTime.ParseExact( input,"MM/dd/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yy")
```

Comment: date_for = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["date_for"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MM/dd/yy"),

Comment: i changed the line of code has this  date_for = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["date_for"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yy"), and  the encapsulation data type has sting date_for  { get; set; }

Comment: code functions well but didn't get the expected output   date_for = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["date_for"].ToString(), "MM/dd/yy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yy"),

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

```
 date_for = DateTime.ParseExact(dr["date_for"].toString(), "dd/mm/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Says ...  Error  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: What is data type of `date_for`

Comment: ["date_for"] is owns to web service Class Element, and yah its a string type

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use DateTime.Parse(), DateTime.TryParse() and 
DateTime.ToString() methods.
```

But DateTime.TryParse return boolean value. It can use to check conditions.

```
DateTime.Parse(Convert.ToString(dr["date_for"])).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

OR

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Convert.ToString(dr["date_for"]), "dd/MM/yy", null);
```

Comment: the line of code didnt work for me , i guess becuse of the encapsulation ! do i need to change the type ?  right now it was declared has

Comment: public string date_for { get; set; }

Comment: No need change type

Comment: Says ... Error Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Now ok. I changed code. Thats come because of cannot convert to string of dr["date_for"] inside Parse()

Comment: And Now it Says {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."} that means do i need to change the data type to public DateTime date_for  { get; set;  } even tho i do get the certain error which is related to Date Format

Comment: Sorry. I have done mistake. Month sholud denote with M. not with m. Now ok.